# bootstrap 4 login template isn't responsive. can you see why?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am in-the-making of a nice login page, mobile first design, using Bootstrap 4.
Used [this snippet](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/dldxB), and was very happy about it!

However, I found out it isn't mobile responsive. only when I disable the touch simulation on Firefox developer tools, it becomes normal size.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: while looking at your snippet , i can literaly see your css properties, i would first suggest a you read more about css and html before jumping to bootstrap .

Comment: check that you have used all the bootstrap 4 cdn or not because i checked your snippet code are working fine in all device.  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: @bhartiparmar which device did you use?

Comment: From laptop i checked this code by inspect. and if this is not responsive still in mobile device then try to use bootstrap 4 class for mobile device col-xs-*.

Comment: You can add your own code snippet, so finding the bug or problem would be easy for everyone. Thank's